# How to set string-based/named template in a knockout custom binding?

Tags: knockout.js

I have a bindingHandler (e.g. myWidget) and I'd like it to set the named template based on properties in the associated view model. I've currently implemented this by adding a handler to the binding:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.myWidget = {

    template: function (viewModel) {
        // return template name based on viewModel properties
    },

    // init, update etc
```

And then in the front end I declare a ko binding:

```
<div data-bind="myWidget: true, template: ko.bindingHandlers.myWidget.template($data)"></div>
```

This works, although I suspect it's not the "right" way to do it if for no other reason than it won't update the template without me adding additional code to subscribe to the relevant vm property changes.

Is there a way to set the template in update()? Or is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: I would like to clarify if there's a particular reason why `myWidget` is passed with a `true` value, can this value be changed to an observable?

Comment: @Adrian the problem with doing this is that an observable will (presumably) be located in the view model. If you read my comment below I'm trying to adhere strictly to MVVM by keeping template names themselves out of the view model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've provided little context, and it feels like you may have an XY-problem. But answering your question straight up, if you want your binding handler to defer creating the content to the built-in `template` binding, I suggest copying [the `foreach` binding's approach](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/master/src/binding/defaultBindings/foreach.js) and do it like this:

```js
"use strict";

ko.bindingHandlers.myWidget = {
    'init': function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        return ko.bindingHandlers['template']['init'](element, valueAccessor);
    },
    'update': function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        return ko.bindingHandlers['template']['update'](element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext);
    }
}

function RootViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  self.obs = ko.observable("a");
}

ko.applyBindings(new RootViewModel());
```

```css
pre { background: white; padding: 10px; color: #333; font: 11px consolas; border: 1px solid #ddd; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<script type="text/html" id="a">Ahh, Template</script>
<script type="text/html" id="b">Bee, Template</script>

<div data-bind="with: obs">
  <div data-bind="myWidget: { name: $data }"></div>
</div>

Change obs: <select data-bind="options: ['a', 'b'], value: obs"></select>

<hr>Debug info: <pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root, null, 2)"></pre>
```

The `name` you pass to `myWidget` will also be passed on to `template` and be picked up. Of course you could fine-tune what you pass to the `init` and `update` of `template` as well, but for the context you had provided the above will suffice.

Comment: thanks, that works perfectly! I wasn't aware the bindingHandlers had a `template` property,but this is plenty for me to RTFM from here on out.

Comment: BTW my rational for trying to do this comes from a position of wanting to maintain good SOC, but given my relative inexperience with knockout I'm perfectly open to being corrected. The way I see it the templates are part of the view, and while the view models should be exposing properties for the consumption by the views they shouldn't be view-aware themselves. It would seem to me that the template names themselves are view-specific properties, so the best place to set named templates is in the custom bindings along with other attributes i.e. css etc. Would you consider this reasoning flawed?