# How to make one item in an observable array change another item in that array

Tags: knockout.js

I have an array of objects with an observable property that is being bound to a group of radio buttons.  The observable property can only have the following values ['Primary', 'Secondary', 'Occasional', 'none']

Here's the HTML.

```
<!--ko foreach: allDriversForPolicy-->
<div class="col-md-2">
    <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
        <div class="">
            <label><input type="radio" value="Primary" data-bind="checked: vehicleDriverType, attr: {name: id}"/>Primary</label>
            <label><input type="radio" value="Secondary" data-bind="checked: vehicleDriverType, attr: {name: id}" />Secondary</label>
            <label><input type="radio" value="Ocasional" data-bind="checked: vehicleDriverType, attr: {name: id}" />Ocasional</label>
            <label><input type="radio" value="" data-bind="checked: vehicleDriverType, attr: {name: id}" />None</label>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
<!--/ko-->
```

And here is the JavaScript to get it running.

```
var SimpleListModel = function() {
    this.allDriversForPolicy = ko.observableArray([
    {'id': 'abe', 'vehicleDriverType': 'Primary'},
    {'id': 'bob', 'vehicleDriverType': 'Secondary'},
    {'id': 'charlie', 'vehicleDriverType': ''}
    ]);
};

ko.applyBindings(new SimpleListModel());
```

jsfiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Maleki/mjgqtkxw/).
The wrinkle I'm running into is an added requirement that out of all the objects there can only be one primary so I'd like the behaviour to be if Primary is selected then go through the array and switch any objects with the observable property set to 'Primary' to 'Secondary'.

How can I do this?

Comment: Please remove any code *not* relevant to the question, and *add* enough code to reproduce your scenario.

Comment: All right I've trimmed it down.  That'll reproduce the basics of what I have now.

Comment: Could you add the JS needed to create a full repro? For an example, see [this recent answer I posted](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35547107/419956), for guidance see [mcve].

Comment: I've added code for a simple reproduction and a link to the jsfiddle I created it in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: you have a rather weird bit of markup with the `a` tag wrapping all the other code. I've removed that bit in my example below.

The requirement you have will be *very* difficult to implement in a MVVM / Knockout style, because you don't have a backing observable for the selected radio button values. Once you change that, you can choose multiple ways to implement your requirement, including:

- Creating [writeable computeds](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computed-writable.html) for the backing observables, where the `write` bit updates the sibling observables;
- Creating subscriptions to all individual backing observables.

Here's an example of the latter option:

```js
var SimpleListModel = function() {
  var self = this;
  
  this.allDriversForPolicy = ko.observableArray([{
    'id': 'abe',
    'vehicleDriverType': ko.observable('Primary')
  }, {
    'id': 'bob',
    'vehicleDriverType': ko.observable('Secondary')
  }, {
    'id': 'charlie',
    'vehicleDriverType': ko.observable('')
  }]);
  
  self.allDriversForPolicy().forEach(function(i) {
    i.vehicleDriverType.subscribe(function(newVal) {
      if (newVal !== 'Primary') return;
      self.allDriversForPolicy().forEach(function(p) {
        if (p !== i && p.vehicleDriverType() === 'Primary') {
          p.vehicleDriverType('');
        }
      });
    });
  });
};

ko.applyBindings(new SimpleListModel());
```

```css
pre { background: white; padding: 10px; color: #333; font: 11px consolas; border: 1px solid #ddd; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<!--ko foreach: allDriversForPolicy-->
<div class="col-md-2">
  <div class="">
    <label>
      <input type="radio" value="Primary" data-bind="checked: vehicleDriverType, attr: {name: id}" />Primary</label>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" value="Secondary" data-bind="checked: vehicleDriverType, attr: {name: id}" />Secondary</label>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" value="Ocasional" data-bind="checked: vehicleDriverType, attr: {name: id}" />Ocasional</label>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" value="" data-bind="checked: vehicleDriverType, attr: {name: id}" />None</label>
  </div>
</div>
<!--/ko-->

<hr>Debug info: <pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root, null, 2)"></pre>
```

PS. I suggest creating a seperate constructor function for the items in that array, which will make for a lot clearer code (the nested `forEach`es will become a lot better if you do).

Comment: Ah sorry about that.  There's an image tag missing in my example(it wasn't necessary for the problem).  My plan is to make the whole thing a thumbnail and have the select list appear when you hover over it.  Clicking on something that isn't the radio button list will bring up a file upload dialog to change the image.  That's the plan anyway.